# Git daemon doesn't work properly when run from xinetd

Tags: linux, git, xinetd

I'm trying to set up a git public repository for my team.

I have installed Git on a linux box (RedHat 5.6).

As a first step, i'm trying to configure Git to use the git protocol, by setting it up to run through xinetd.

Here's the contents of /etc/xinetd.d/git-daemon:

```
# default: off
# description: The git server offers access to git repositories
service git
{
        disable = no
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 9418
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = nobody
        server          = /usr/bin/git/git
        log_type = FILE /var/log/git-daemon
        server_args     = daemon --verbose --inetd --export-all --base-path=/tmp
        log_on_failure  += USERID
}
```

According to /var/log/messages the service is started correctly.

When trying to clone a test (bare) repository, i am getting a failure:

```
C:\Users\ltal>git clone git://10.161.202.45/lior-test.git c:\liorssf
Cloning into c:\liorssf...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: fata
```

Running the same command that is configured for xinetd from the shell seems to work fine:

```
/usr/bin/git/git daemon --verbose --export-all --base-path=/tmp &
```

Now cloning works.

What am i doing wrong here? Can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#protocol_error:_bad_line_length_character

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't contain anything useful for my case...

Comment: I see that my windows machine has Git 1.7.3 while the server has 1.7.6. Trying to upgrade to match versions and see if that will solve the problem.

Comment: Both at version 1.7.6, still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the user that i've used for setting up xinetd.

I changed this to be root (for now), and i can now happily clone the repository from other clients.

Answer (score 1):

"fata" is the beginning of "fatal", `git clone` truncates it, so you may directly try to use `nc 10.161.202.45 9418` to get the full message returned by git daemon, then if this is not enough for you to fix it, you may temporarily replace `/usr/bin/git` by `/usr/bin/strace` in the server field of the xinetd config, and prepend `-f /usr/bin/git` to the `server_args` field. It's likely a permissions error, maybe you have a `/.git/` own by root, and `git daemon` likely run as less privileged `git` user, chokes when trying to read `/.git/config`…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `/usr/bin/git` is not in the PATH.

Add `env += GIT_TRACE=/tmp/git-xinetd.log` into the `/etc/xinetd.d/git-daemon` and try again to see what does log say?

Comment: This just gives a trace of the command that runs: trace: exec: 'git-daemon' '--verbose' '--inetd' '--export-all' '--base-path=/tmp'
trace: run_command: 'git-daemon' '--verbose' '--inetd' '--export-all' '--base-path=/tmp'

Comment: Also, running git from any directory i am in seems to work, so i don't believe this is a PATH issue.

Comment: Did you try `git clone` from client after adding?

Comment: What do you mean git clone from the client? The output i pasted here was the one displayed when i try to run git clone from my windows client box.

Comment: Your path may not be the same path that `xinetd` is operating with. That said, it appears that the daemon command is running appropriately. I think you may need to look at a lower level... I'd start confirming each step with external tools -- atop, wireshark, etc. Also, consider the possibility of a version mismatch.

Comment: I mean after running `git clone` from your Windows, is there anything in `git-xinetd.log`.

Comment: I have fixed the original problem. I change the user from NOBODY to root (for now). this made it work.